# Differentiating actions from the View versus directly from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm, view

Is there any way to know when ViewModel properties are being updated as a direct result of changes in the View, as opposed to updating the ViewModel properties directly (like from within a Controller or anyone else who has access to the ViewModel)?

Case in point, I have a monitoring station application.

- I'm using SignalR to listen to network notifications from within a Controller, and notifications trigger updates to the ViewModel for the View. (Pretty Basic)
- I also register a callback with the PropertyChanged notifier, because there are higher-level calculations that must be recalculated locally when specific ViewModel properties are set. (Again, Textbookishly Basic)

However, I also want to be able to update the View manually (and not just be content with outside notifications updating the ViewModel) to make the application two-way. I want changes I make to the View to also be able to update ViewModel properties and send SignalR notifications of changed values via the Controller.

My problem is that from the Controller the only way I have to know when properties are updated is through the PropertyChanged notification. However, the PropertyChanged notification also fires when the Controller sets the property via the ViewModel directly. I need to know when the View changes a ViewModel property, and not when the ViewModel property is changed via the Controller (or anyone other than the View). Otherwise my Controller is spewing notifications every time the ViewModel is updated by something other than the View, whereas I only want my Controller to react when updates are made to properties via the View.

Is there a construct or a design pattern that allows me to determine this (without having a copy of the ViewModel that the Controller owns and comparing with the ViewModel that the View owns)?

Comment: You could have property `set` inspect the stack via `(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()).GetFrame(1)`. But that's a horror. The proper way to do this is to design classes that do precisely what you want and no more. It's no good to start with a design that does things you don't want, and then add extra kludges to remove that undesired behavior. You can write a viewmodel that supports silent property value changes, though it seems unwise: Shouldn't the View reflect the vm's state? That's the whole point.

Comment: I think you may want a Model that the controller manipulates, which sends no updates. Then you have a viewmodel that interacts with the view. The controller decides when changes from the model go to the viewmodel or vice versa. I dunno, that's off the top of my head. You need some traffic cop that knows what's going on with everybody, and that's not the viewmodel. What you're doing is like trying to write a state machine with three state variables instead of one. It's a natural mess.

Comment: If you want to tell the difference between two or more separate mechanisms of updating the property, provide a different way to update the property for each. E.g. expose the same value in different properties (binding one property to the view, letting other code set via the other), or provide explicit methods for the non-binding scenarios, etc. As stated your question is way too broad, as there are _lots_ of different ways to accomplish this. Post a good [mcve], tell us exactly what you want the code to do, and explain what _specifically_ you are having trouble with toward that goal.